# Transition probability in a non-homogenous continuous time Markov model along a given fixed path of states, say s1->s2->s3?

Tags: transition, probability, markov

In a non-homogenous, continuous time Markov model, the Nelson-Aalen estimator of the transition matrix P(s,t) estimates the transition probability in the time interval [s,t] from any state s1 to any other state s2.

Is it possible to estimate the transition probability within the time interval [s,t] ***along a given fixed path of adjacent states, say s1->s2->s3***?

In other words: only such transitions are of interested which do not deviate from s1->s2->s3, e.g. s1->s4->s2->s3 is not allowed.

It is clear that this is not given by the P(s,t)(1,3), i.e. the matrix element in 1st row and 3 column, because this estimates the transition probability of ALL paths from 1->3.

Is there any idea how to estimate the transition probability along a given path?

Any idea would be very appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: maybe post on different overflow. like computer science

Comment: here is mainly related to programming, cross validated might work too or mathematics

Comment: This question would be more appropriate for another Stack site, like compSci.